# Socketio Websocket on https does not work

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using socket io to sent some notifications Messages to the web ui, but currently I get this error message:

> https://12.123.12.12:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MMfbmct
>   0 ()

My socket.js file:

```
 var fs    = require('fs');
 var app = require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/serverKey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/serverCrt.pem')
 }, handler);
var io    = require('socket.io')(app);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

var Redis = require('ioredis');

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('');
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {});

// ...

// run server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server running!');
});
```

The eventjs file tries to get the data from the socket and do stuff on the ui, this worked a while ago and I do not remember how I declared the socket variable

```
// I tried following declarations but none work
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
var socket = io('http://123.123.123.123:3000'); // sever ip
var socket = io('https://localhost:3000');
var socket = io('https://123.123.123.123:3000'); // sever ip

socket.on('signed-in-channel:App\\Events\\UserSignedIn', (data) => {
    // some stuff
});
```

How do I declare the socket properly?